# Is TCP the best method for communication between Go programs in the same host?

Tags: http, go, tcp

Suppose I have two separated Go programs running in my localhost, is TCP the best method for transferring data between the two programs in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The TCP/IP stack is slow, especially the TCP part. So in terms of performance you better use local inter-process communication methods, like a shared memory between your applications or Unix sockets.

If you MUST use a network stack to communicate (say, you plan to move applications between hosts), then UDP or raw sockets are the best options in terms of performance.

And only if you:

1. must use a network and
2. you need a reliable communication channel, then TCP is a good option.

So just walk through your requirements and decide if it is a best method *for you.*

Comment: Would the shared memory method be using channels? I would like to decouple the program so that if one part fails, the other parts can still function, which was why I didn't consider using channels.

Comment: It might be worth a mention, that UDP isn't reliable. TCP cares about retransmission of packages which got lost, but UDP don't. However, this _probably_ won't happen on the same host.

Comment: @Pig no, shared memory is just a memory that may be simultaneously accessed by multiple programs. The whole burden of organizing and synchronizing the access to this memory is on the programmer, but that is the fastest way of IPC on the same host. There are a variety of techniques for that. Usually you just create a (lockless) queue of "messages" in this shared memory. If one part of the communication fails, your queue is just empty. Once the other part is up, there are new messages in the queue...

Answer (score 0):

It would work and give additional freedom to have the two programs run on different computers. But it is not the best in terms of performance.

For good performance, shared memory comes to mind.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory
Maybe you could describe a bit more what exactly you want to do.